# Full Apache config migration

Tags: linux, apache, migration

I searched alot and didn't find an applicable answer.

I have a working LAMP setup on Ubuntu machine and I have to migrate to a new server in a different country.
The old server is 11.10, the new server is 12.04LTS.

My problem is that I simply can not remember the steps I followed when I configured the current server which is not the basic LAMP install.
It is Apache with FastCGI, SuEXEC, a GD library, worker MPM and all sitting on top of a mhddfs system. There are also other configs I've changed and I can not recall what they are. 
Because of the complexity of the setup, my attempts to migrate to the new server fail. I get permissions errors, cgi problems etc.

Therefore my question is :
Is there a sane way to simply tar a full backup of the current web server installation, including MySQL, Php amd the apache server with all configs, and then move it to the new machine?

I shall be forever thankful on any advise. So far non of thise I found here gave me an answer.

Thanks!

Comment: Oh shit. Guess next time you will think of writing a documentation...

Comment: I definately would. But this is not really helping right now